# c# phone 8.1 change jpeg quality

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want to capture an image from the camera, reduce its size AND reduce the Quality.

this is my function so far:

```
private async void BildSpeichern(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuFlyoutItem FO = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
    StorageFile datei = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(_viewmodel.DateiPfad);

    string neuerDateiName=datei.Name + "___" + FO.CommandParameter.ToString();
    await datei.RenameAsync(neuerDateiName);
    _viewmodel.DateiPfad = datei.Path;

    using (var sourceStream = await datei.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, sourceStream);


        uint oriWidth = decoder.PixelWidth;
        uint oriHeight = decoder.PixelHeight;

        uint tarWidth;
        uint tarHeight;

        if (oriWidth > oriHeight)
        {
            tarWidth = 1024;
            tarHeight = (uint)((float)tarWidth / (float)oriWidth * (float)oriHeight);
        }
        else
        {
            tarHeight = 1024;
            tarWidth = (uint)((float)tarHeight / (float)oriHeight * (float)oriWidth);
        }

        InMemoryRandomAccessStream IS = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(IS, decoder);
        decoder = null;
        encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = tarHeight;
        encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = tarWidth;
        await encoder.FlushAsync();

    }
    await datei.CopyAsync(Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary,"TEST.JPG",NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    FotoVorschau.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    FotoAnzeige.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    AufnahmeStackpanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    VorschauStackpanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    FotoAnzeige.Source = null;
    _viewmodel.DateiPfad = null;
}
```

the only thing I'm missing is the compression, or let's better say the reduced quality of the resulting JPEG-Image.

The only examples i've found uses System.Drawing, but that's not useable in a Windows Phone 8.1 Project ... does anybody know how to achieve this?

EDIT:
this is my new part of the function, but the Image won't get resized and won't get compressed:

```
using (var sourceStream = await datei.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(sourceStream);


                uint oriWidth = decoder.PixelWidth;
                uint oriHeight = decoder.PixelHeight;

                uint tarWidth;
                uint tarHeight;

                if (oriWidth > oriHeight)
                {
                    tarWidth = 1024;
                    tarHeight = (uint)((float)tarWidth / (float)oriWidth * (float)oriHeight);
                }
                else
                {
                    tarHeight = 1024;
                    tarWidth = (uint)((float)tarHeight / (float)oriHeight * (float)oriWidth);
                }

                var propertySet = new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPropertySet();
                var qualityValue = new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapTypedValue(
                    0.6,
                    Windows.Foundation.PropertyType.Single
                    );

                propertySet.Add("ImageQuality", qualityValue);

                BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, sourceStream, propertySet);
                PixelDataProvider pd = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
                encoder.SetPixelData(decoder.BitmapPixelFormat, decoder.BitmapAlphaMode, oriWidth, oriHeight, decoder.DpiX, decoder.DpiY, pd.DetachPixelData());
                decoder = null;

                encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = tarHeight;
                encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = tarWidth;
                encoder.BitmapTransform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Cubic;

                await encoder.FlushAsync();
                sourceStream.Dispose();

            }
```

Answer (score 3):

The link Robert mentioned opened the HTML version of the article for me, but the [XAML one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ709940(v=win.10).aspx) has some good samples:

```
IAsyncOperation<BitmapEncoder> CreateEncoderWithEncodingOptionsAsync(
    Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream stream
    )
{
    var propertySet = new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPropertySet();
    var qualityValue = new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapTypedValue(
        1.0, // Maximum quality
        Windows.Foundation.PropertyType.Single
        );

    propertySet.Add("ImageQuality", qualityValue);
    return Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(
        Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId,
        stream,
        propertySet
        );

    // Encoder is initialized with encoding options.
}
```

Comment: thanks, i tested a bit but i does not work, think i'm missing soething ;(

Answer (score 0):

It is worthwile to have a look at the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions.savejpeg(v=vs.105).aspx

The Extensions.SaveJpeg method in System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace. Particularly the quality parameter of this method:

quality
Type: System.Int32
This parameter represents the quality of the JPEG photo with a range between 0 and 100, with 100 being the best photo quality. We recommend that you do not fall lower than a value of 70. because JPEG picture quality diminishes significantly below that level.

And then it could be called with code such as the following:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isostream = iso.CreateFile(strImageName)) 
{                    
    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(); 
    bitmap.SetSource(stream); 
    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap); 
    // Encode WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream. 
    Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, isostream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85); 
    isostream.Close(); 
}
```

And here is some extra info about encoding options, with further details about the encoding options for ImageQuality.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj218354.aspx

Comment: thanks for your effort, but your example is not useable in a Windows Phone 8.1 Project ;(

Comment: The `System.Windows.Media.*` namespaces might not be usable, but that last link should actually help you. Here's the XAML version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ709940(v=win.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Example of Filip works, but one line code is missing in the end:

```
propertySet.Add("ImageQuality", qualityValue);
```

You can find example at [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging)

```
IAsyncOperation<BitmapEncoder> CreateEncoderWithEncodingOptionsAsync(
Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream stream)
{
var propertySet = new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPropertySet();
var qualityValue = new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapTypedValue(
    1.0, // Maximum quality
    Windows.Foundation.PropertyType.Single
    );

propertySet.Add("ImageQuality", qualityValue);
return Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(
    Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId,
    stream,
    propertySet
    );
propertySet.Add("ImageQuality", qualityValue);
}
```